# Single and Double tap on the Cell does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a simple table with a few cells inside which I have a label and a circle. I want to change the label depending on the tap (single or double). For that I need to know the indexPath of the cell, so I added delegates. Taps are recognized but when I try to push the info about the cells to ViewController (functions tableViewCell(singleTapActionDelegatedFrom & doubleTapActionDelegatedFrom) nothing seems to work

**ViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

var elements: [[Int16]] = Array(repeating:Array(repeating:0, count:2), count:10)

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableViewCell(singleTapActionDelegatedFrom cell: TableViewCell)
    {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        print("singleTap \(String(describing: indexPath)) ")
    }

    func tableViewCell(doubleTapActionDelegatedFrom cell: TableViewCell)
    {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        print("doubleTap \(String(describing: indexPath)) ")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return elements.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        if(elements[indexPath.row][1] == 1) //if red
        {
            cell.Label.text = String(elements[indexPath.row][0] * 3)
            cell.Circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        else //if blue
        {
            cell.Label.text = String(elements[indexPath.row][0])
            cell.Circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }

        cell.delegate? = self as! TableViewCellDelegate

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.height/10
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        for i in 0..<elements.count
        {
            elements[i][0] = Int16(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
            elements[i][1] = Int16(Int(arc4random_uniform(2)))
        }

        Memory().save(entity: elements)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
}
```

**TableViewCell.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?
    private var tapCounter = 0

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        Circle.layer.cornerRadius = Circle.frame.width / 2

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapAction))
        addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func tapAction()
    {

        if tapCounter == 0
        {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async
            {
                usleep(250000)
                if self.tapCounter > 1
                {
                    self.doubleTapAction()
                }
                else
                {
                    self.singleTapAction()
                }
                self.tapCounter = 0
            }
        }
        tapCounter += 1
    }

    func singleTapAction() {
        delegate?.tableViewCell(singleTapActionDelegatedFrom: self)
    }

    func doubleTapAction() {
        delegate?.tableViewCell(doubleTapActionDelegatedFrom: self)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Circle: UIView!
}
```

**TableViewCellDelegate:**

```
protocol TableViewCellDelegate
{
    func tableViewCell(singleTapActionDelegatedFrom cell: TableViewCell)
    func tableViewCell(doubleTapActionDelegatedFrom cell: TableViewCell)
}
```

Comment: I can see a mistake. `ViewController` should adopt `TableViewCellDelegate` protocol. And as touch action is recognized, print the value of delegate at `delegate?.tableViewCell(singleTapActionDelegatedFrom: self)` and see if it has the correct value

Comment: Tbh I don't know what you mean by "ViewController should adopt TableViewCellDelegate". VC recognizes TableViewCellDelegate

Comment: What Dinesh is trying to say, is that you haven't declared your ViewController as conforming to the `TableViewCellDelegate` protocol - at least not in the snippet. You should try to replace your class definition with this: `class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewCellDelegate` and then in `cellForRow` you don't need to force cast `self` to the protocol, so just do `cell.delegate? = self`. The force cast is probably enforced by the compiler, because you haven't declared the class as conforming to the protocol in its declaration